# How do I run a .lua script?

Tags: lua, cmd

I need to execute a .lua script using windows command line (cmd).
I've got my .lua file in the same folder in which my lua.exe is.

I've tried several ways of running the file but I can't figure out how to do it. =(

(I also have the same script with the extension .out)

Comment: Run Lua Run ...

Comment: Windows: too localized.

Comment: As much as I love Linux over Windows, I **strongly disagree** with this being closed. There is a MASSIVE number of Windows machines, and I'm certain there are plenty of people trying to use Lua on them.

Comment: Disagree with the reason for closing this! "How to run lua script on windows?" is too localized? really?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`C:\path\to\lua.exe file_name.lua`
OR
`lua file_name.lua` if you've set  up envrioment variables. If the prior doesn't work, simply drag and drop the `file_name.lua` onto the `lua.exe`.

Comment: Ohh... It's so simple!
I was getting errors over and over again, them I've downloaded another .exe and it worked!
Thank you!

Comment: @matheusesp: If you want to thank him, accept his answer (with the checkmark beside the answer).