# How to run a lua file without CMD

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, python-3.x, lua

I have a windows 7 .I had the doubt of running a lua executable file , I've done it with python using Python Launcher, any ideas how to do it with Lua?

Comment: Are you asking "how to build lua.exe on windows"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a .lua script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692580/how-do-i-run-a-lua-script)

Answer (score 0):

For Lua you need to build binaries or use community premade binaries.

Download Lua and build it manually: https://www.lua.org/download.html

Example of community premade binaries: http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/